# Partner Center Java SDK (Azure)

Tags: java, azure, sdk

I need your help, I am using Azure partner center SDK (java) to create a link with azure cloud.
I am using the following code to do the authentication part and it was mentioned in Microsoft Documentation.

```
IAggregatePartner partnerOperations = PartnerCredentials.getInstance().generateByApplicationCredentials(
    "ApplicationId"
    "ApplicationSecret",
    "AccountId");
```

but when I run the code this error appears:

```
**Exception in thread "main" PartnerException: ErrorCategory: NOT_SPECIFIED, ServiceErrorPayload: null, Context: null, Base Description: com.microsoft.store.partnercenter.exception.PartnerException: Failed to do the application AAD login
    at com.microsoft.store.partnercenter.extensions.ApplicationPartnerCredentials.authenticate(ApplicationPartnerCredentials.java:172)
    at com.microsoft.store.partnercenter.extensions.PartnerCredentials.generateByApplicationCredentials(PartnerCredentials.java:69)
    at com.microsoft.store.partnercenter.extensions.PartnerCredentials.generateByApplicationCredentials(PartnerCredentials.java:50)
    at com.contoso.PartnerApp.App.main(App.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authority Uri should have at least one segment in the path (i.e. https://<host>/<path>/...)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.Authority.detectAuthorityType(Authority.java:72)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientApplicationBase$Builder.authority(ClientApplicationBase.java:257)
    at com.microsoft.store.partnercenter.extensions.ApplicationPartnerCredentials.authenticate(ApplicationPartnerCredentials.java:155)**
    ... 3 more
```

Thanks for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, you do not provide effective authority Uri. If you want to finish app authentication with Azure partner center SDK (java), I suggest you use the method

```
 public IPartnerCredentials generateByApplicationCredentials(String clientId, String applicationSecret,
                                                                        String aadApplicationDomain,
                                                                        String aadAuthorityEndpoint,
                                                                        String graphEndpoint
```

For example

1. update web app and configure required permissions. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/create-apps-for-partner-center-for-microsoft-national-clouds#web-apps.
2. Get the information you need in Partner Center
   [image]
3. Write code

```
        String clientId="the applicationId of your app you create";
        String applicationSecret="the app secrret";
        String aadApplicationDomain ="your account id ";
        String aadAuthorityEndpoint="https://login.windows.net/";
        String graphEndpoint="https://graph.windows.net";

        IPartnerCredentials appCred = PartnerCredentials.getInstance().generateByApplicationCredentials( clientId,applicationSecret,aadApplicationDomain,aadAuthorityEndpoint,graphEndpoint);

        IAggregatePartner partnerOperations = PartnerService.getInstance().createPartnerOperations(appCred);

        Customer customer = partnerOperations.getCustomers().byId("e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb").get();
        System.out.print("The custom's Commerce ID : " + customer.getCommerceId());
```

[image]

### Update

Regarding how to configure permissions, please refer to the following pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you it worked , but concerning the document that you have sent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/create-apps-for-partner-center-for-microsoft-national-clouds                                                                                              in the API access configuration we don't have the Windows Azure Active Directory permissions, can you send us a screenshot of this tap from your Azure Portal (App registration)

Comment: @DinaIbrahim The Windows Azure Active Directory permissions is Azure AD Graph API permissions.